# WP Build-In Post selector for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts

I'm quite sure to remember any WP build-in function that generates post selector based on several args (post_type, etc.) like on the nav-menus admin page, here a screenshot:

[image]

Is there something like this or must I have been dreaming about it? How would you implement this?

Comment: Could you please clarify what a "post selector based on several args" is?

Comment: See my update, added a screenshot.

Comment: sweet dreams ;-) Sounds similar to [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/zoninator/) Automattic plugin